# Add metadata in your RNN model after embedding layer with shared weights

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I have a embedding matrix with shared weights for text threads after which I wanted to add metadata into my model. However, adding a new layer using same function as before for initializing model layers is giving me dimension errors. Can someone tell me how I can proceed?

```python
def build_post_submodel(arch='cnn', isEmbedding = True):
    """
    Creates and returns a function from Input to a chain of layer with shared weights for embedding matrix of different posts in our thread.
    """
    if isEmbedding:
     layers = [ Embedding(vocab_size,EMBEDDING_DIM,input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)]
        if arch == 'cnn':
            layers.extend([
                Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
                MaxPooling1D(50),
                Flatten()
            ])
        elif arch == 'average':
            layers.extend([
                Masking(mask_value=WORD_PADDING_VALUE),
                # Average()
                Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1), output_shape=lambda s: (s[0], s[2]))
            ])
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown post architecture: %s' % arch)
    else:
        layers = [Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
                    MaxPooling1D(50),
                    Flatten()]

    def composed_layers(x):
        for layer in layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x

    return composed_layers


post_submodel = build_post_submodel(post_arch, True)

# create an input for each post
input_tensors = []
encoded_posts = []
for i in range(use_number_of_posts):
    post_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    input_tensors.append(post_input)
    encoded_post = post_submodel(post_input)
    encoded_posts.append(encoded_post)

#trying to add metadata to my model    
post_submodel = build_post_submodel(post_arch, False)
metadata_tensor = Input(shape=np.array(metadata_train).shape)
input_tensors.append(metadata_input)
encoded_post = post_submodel(metadata_input)
encoded_posts.append(encoded_post)

merged_vector = concatenate(encoded_posts, axis=-1)
preds = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(merged_vector)
model = Model(input_tensors, preds)    
model.summary()
```

Comment: Can you post information about error as well?

Comment: In encoded_post = post_submodel(metadata_input) referencing   x = layer(x) in composed_layers(), I am getting ERROR: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_10: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2